# Determine, if horz/vert scrollbar shown on control?

Tags: lazarus

Such WinAPI article shows how to see if h/v scrollbar shown: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299686
I need same info but for Lazarus controls (Win/Linux, control is TMemo, TScrollbox, TListview...). How to?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use a) LCLType, b) LCLIntf,
then call `GetScrollInfo` with Handle

```
function form1.GetScrollbarVisible(ForVertBar: boolean): boolean;
const
  cKind: array[boolean] of integer = (SB_HORZ, SB_VERT);
var
  si: TScrollInfo;
begin
  FillChar(si, SizeOf(si), 0);
  si.cbSize:= SizeOf(si);
  si.fMask:= SIF_ALL;
  GetScrollInfo(Handle, cKind[ForVertBar], si);
  Result:= Longword(si.nMax) > Longword(si.nPage);
end;
```